# SQL join that displays left table even if right table doesn't match where

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join, left-join

I have 2 tables, defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
`pid` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`description` TEXT,
`qty` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`category` ENUM( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`price` DECIMAL( 7, 2 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `discount` (
`did` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`pid` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`sDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`eDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`dPrice` DECIMAL( 7, 2 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ( `pid` ) REFERENCES `product`(`pid`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I am trying to get a result of exactly 1 row for every product and a `NULL` dPrice or the dPrice if there's a discount entry with `sDate < NOW()` and `eDate > NOW()`.

I tried:

```
select p.pid, name, price, dPrice, qty
from product p left join discount d
on p.pid = d.pid
where d.sDate<now() and d.eDate>now();
```

The problem with this is it returned only products with a valid discount. Products with no discount or expired / future discounts are not shown.

Next I tried:

```
select p.pid, name, price, dPrice, qty
from product p left join discount d
on p.pid = d.pid
where (d.sDate<now() and d.eDate>now()) or dPrice is null;
```

This came 1 step closer to my desired result, where it listed products with valid discounts and products with no discounts, but I'm still missing the products with expired / future discounts defined.

Checking that only 1 discount is active at any time is done in PHP and need not be included in this statement. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what database system? what version??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select p.pid, name, price, dPrice, qty
from product p 

left join discount d on p.pid = d.pid and d.sDate<now() and d.eDate>now()
```

More efficient and more "standard" than a subquery.

Comment: It's the same as the accepted answer, but I posted this earlier ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
SELECT p.name, d.dPrice
FROM   product p LEFT JOIN discount d
ON     p.pid = d.pid AND now() BETWEEN d.sDate AND d.eDate
```

Comment: LOL!! 3 ways to get the job done and I can't come up with one! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a subquery to return a filtered version of `discount` that you can then left join with `product`.

```
select p.pid, name, price, dPrice, qty
from product p left join
(select * from discount where sDate<now() and eDate>now()) d
on p.pid = d.pid;
```

(There may be a slight error in the SQL syntax here, but you get the idea: since you only want the `WHERE` clause to apply to one table, you apply it to that table in a subquery and then join the result data set, instead of joining the tables first and then filtering.)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what [Outer Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_join) have been invented for.

`select p.*,d.dPrice from product p left outer join discount d on p.pid=d.pid and now() between d.sDate and d.eDate`

You can use abbreviation `left join` instead of full `left outer join`. However, it's still good to remember that they are outer joins as opposed to usual inner joins.